# Continuous limits of Hex on larger and larger boards

Tags: infinite-games

Consider the game of Hex on a variable sized $n \times n$ board.  Remap each board to be a discrete subset of the unit square $[0,1]^2$.  Optimal games are now finite sequences on the unit square.  We can make optimal play more interesting by making the losing side maximize the length of the game.

If we fix a particular optimal sequence for each $n$, we can pass to a sequence of $n$'s so that all prefixes of the optimal games converge.  This gives a particular "limit optimal game" which is an infinite sequence of points in $[0,1]^2$.

**Questions:**

1. What does this limit optimal game look like?  In the uninteresting direction, it could just be $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right), \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right), \ldots$ repeating; this would be the case if optimal play spends a longer and longer time arbitrarily close to the center as $n$ increases.  The more interesting case would be if optimal play spread out around the square, increasing the level of detail as the game progresses.
2. Are there natural rules for Hex on a continuous board so that the limit sequence is optimal play for the continuous game?

Comment: page 26 of https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503313 may be of interest

Comment: ...and perhaps also page 7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508580